# Orchestrate database scripts that are stored in aws aurora serverless(postgresql) database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, serverless, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

Just wondering if there are any native AWS options to  Orchestrate database scripts which are stored in AWS aurora serverless(postgresql).

ex: lets say if we have below three database scripts(functions) that we want to execute in sequence

1. select get_data();
2. select transform_data();
3. select load_data();

Is there any AWS native services that we can use to orchestrate above scripts..

Answer (score 2):

You could use AWS Batch to run jobs efficiently. AWS Batch is a managed service that abstracts the complexities of provisioning, managing, monitoring, and scaling your computing jobs, and enables you to easily and efficiently run jobs on AWS. Additionally, AWS Batch enables you to build jobs using the language of your choice and deploy it as a Docker container.

Now, for orchestrate your AWS Batch job you can use AWS Step Functions. Step Functions is a serverless function orchestrator that makes it easy to sequence calls to AWS services into business-critical applications.

You take take as reference following article how use AWS Batch and AWS Step Functions

[Replace self-managed database scheduler batch jobs using AWS native solutions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/replace-self-managed-database-scheduler-batch-jobs-using-aws-native-solutions/)

Another simple solution is use AWS Batch and AWS EventBridge Scheduler

[How to schedule and execute Amazon RDS jobs using AWS Batch and CloudWatch rules](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-batch-rds-job-scheduling)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way would be using a lambda function to execute those three statements one after the other. If for some reason you want to have them executed on different lambda functions, you could always use step functions to orchestrate the next lambda to start only after successfully executing the previous one.

If you need to schedule automatic execution of your lambda function, you can achieve cron-like functionality using [cloudwatch events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents.html) with lambda

Comment: Execution time of each function would be greater than 15 min.. I think using lambda has a limitation on execution time..lambda runs at max for 15 min..So looking for an alternative option to lambda...Any suggestions ?

Comment: If you have a way of querying your database to know if the previous step succeeded, you could orchestrate with step functions. The first function would trigger the first SQL function. Lambda would timeout, but that is fine as your database would still execute the job. Then a second function could be periodically invoked to check if the step finished, and then you can move on to the next. If that's not an option, then AWS Data Pipeline could work. It supports RDS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-sqldatanode.html

Comment: An alternative to AWS Data Pipeline is AWS Glue Jobs. The nice thing about it is you can set up the whole thing visually using their AWS Glue Studio. Not sure if it is a bit overkill for what you need, but running SQL statements one after another is supported